# Indian Citizen travelling on advance parole to USA

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas

I am an Indian citizen who lives in the USA, travelling from USA to India through ROME FIUMICINO, ITALY airport and returning from India to USA through the same airport in Italy. I am travelling with an advance parole document and don't have a visa stamped in the passport.  My stopover is around 3 hours.  Please advise if I need a transit visa for Italy or can travel to the USA (on return) based on approved advance parole.

Comment: What is an Advanced Payroll??? Do you mean _Advance Parole_? An _Advance Parole_ (Form I-512) allows you to _temporarily leave the USA without abandoning a Green Card application_, nothing else. It is not a visa, and has no meaning to any other country.

Comment: How do you intend to enter India? What happened to your Indian passport?

Comment: @MichaelHampton while the question does not explicitly mention an Indian passport, there is no particular reason to think that the asker of the question lacks one.  In fact, the mention that there is no visa in the passport probably implies that there is a passport that doesn't have a visa rather than that there is no passport at all.

Answer (score 1):

Citizens of India [do not require airport transit visas in Italy (pdf)](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/annex_7b_atv-national_lists_en.pdf), so you do not need a visa for this trip.

The advance parole document will allow you to travel to the US without a visa.  That is, after all, [its sole purpose](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/advance-parole).